# Is it even possible to reword my question to be relevant?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

So [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1411436/is-the-360-extreme-browser-safe-to-install) is my question. Now I get why it was put on hold and I am not going to dispute that.

Though I would like to point out that I am not asking for a product recomendation, service or learning material, though I can see why it seams like I am. (Although granted, learning material may/does apply.)

The [article](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/qihoo-360-secure-the-most-popular-browser-youve-never-heard-of--cms-24074) that has me most woried about 360 has references to the specifics, but those links are not functional anymore and I really do not know more about this subject than this.

Assuming that the claims in the article are correct, the best rewording I can think of is to ask something like this:

*In 2019 is the 360 Safe browser still known to rewrite Windows DLLs and does it still masquerade as official Microsoft patches in updates?*

Though really this is about as much details as I can give, because this is all I have and I am not sure its enough.

I do think this is a relavent super user question because 360 is a very important browser in China and if you need to test with it, it would be nice to know what kind of risks are assosiated with it. We can't be the only web development firm trying to find info on this.

Now right now our paranioa it way up, so we will be installing the browser on an isolated virtual machine for testing, but it would be good to know what the browser is known to do in 2019. The main issue being if developers can install it onto their local machines for testing like with the other browsers we support.

There is no question of can we use it (we must test on it), the only question is how paranoid should we be? So I guess if I would reword the question to ask about the *Windows DLL-s* and *Microsoft patches*, would it be enough, or should I simply delete the question and take the hit? Would not like to get downvoted again on this, because my rep is non-existent in super user as is, this is why I am asking help on meta, better to delete the question myself then risk more downvotes.

Comment: We also have a sister site focusing on security side, [security.se], though you still need to make the question specific enough to be answerable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Though I would like to point out that I am not asking for a product recommendation, service or learning material, though I can see why it seems like I am. (Although granted, learning material may/does apply.)

While you might not be asking for a product recommendation, you are seeking our opinion,  in order to determine if a browser can be trusted.  Questions seeking the communities opinion is equally out of scope as a question seeking a product recommendation.

> The main issue is if developers can install it onto their local machines for testing like with the other browsers we support.

If you are worried from a security point of view, there are alternatives to installing it and connecting it to your IT infrastructure, but you would have to do proper research on what those alternatives might before asking a question about them.

> There is no question of can we use it (we must test on it), the only question is how paranoid should we be?

This really isn't a question the community can answer.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but I am guessing that your recomendation would be to simply delete the question and take the hit from the deletion?

Comment: I never recommend a user delete a question if they can help it.  I answered your questions, about the question as it was asked, and simply listed the possible issues that I identified.  I am a single user, what is clear though, you would need to improve it significantly in order for it to be reopened.