# How can a question about a deleted question be a hot meta question?

Tags: discussion, questions

This [Is it even possible to reword my question to be relevant?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13583/is-it-even-possible-to-reword-my-question-to-be-relevant?cb=1) has a link to the deleted question.

Why is it on Hot Meta Posts?

Answer (score 5):

#### Why is it on Hot Meta posts?

The question is **a discussion question not marked status-completed, scoring
at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks**.

The algorithm for deciding Hot Meta Posts is as follows:

> - If there is a community moderator election, a link to it appears in the bulletin.
> - Events can be created with a start date and time, an end date and time, a simple title, and a link to something somewhere on the
>     network. Current or upcoming events are listed, with those starting or
>     ending nearest to the current time shown first.
> - If there are fewer than 4 events, blog posts from the Stack Exchange blog are added to the list. A maximum of two posts will be
>     shown, and only those posted in the past n days, where n is currently
>     10 on International versions of Stack Overflow, and 5 everywhere else.
>     International sites have their own feeds on the company blog and do
>     not list posts from the main English feed.
> - If there are still fewer than 4 items listed, then featured meta posts are shown.
> - If there are still under 4 items, the rest of the space is filled with **hot discussion questions not marked status-completed, scoring
>     at least 3 and posted within the past two weeks**. These are picked
>     semi-randomly. (Note that the timing, score and tags can be adjusted
>     per-site to suit the needs of each community)

(emphasis mine)

Source 
[What criteria is used to select the links that appear in the community bulletin (events / featured / hot meta posts / blog) sidebar block?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130893/267099), answer by [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)

Comment: Couldn't the criteria be changed to include "Are all the links valid"?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald The link to your question in the Hot Meta Posts **is** valid. I don't think that there is any intention to ensure that links **contained** in the question are valid. That would be too much work. In any case the link to the deleted question is still valid for 10K+ rep users.